# Change parameter in the function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I saw some websites talking about that there's a better way of using parameters in a function and also that object literal is a good way of making the code better and faster.

I tried to change using destructuring but didn't work.

I have this function code that I am using to create a code snippet in javascript. I want to know if I can make it look better since I think this code I did is not looking professionally well.

```js
const create = function (t, v, p) {
        let n = document.createElement(t);
        n.innerHTML = v;
        p.appendChild(n);
        return n;
    };
    // create the list for reference
    let ul = create('ul', null, document.body);
```

here is the full JS code

```js
const createsnippets = function (e) {
    // the reference node -- we atually have one ID for headlines 
    let headlines = document.getElementById('headlines');
    // utility function to add new HTML DOM element 
    const create = function (t, v, p) {
        let n = document.createElement(t);
        n.innerHTML = v;
        p.appendChild(n);
        return n;
    };
    // create the list for reference
    let ul = create('ul', null, document.body);

    // find all newsarticle classess and add then to snippet in sequence
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article.newsarticle > h4')).forEach(function (h4) {
        create('li', h4.textContent + ' ... ' + h4.nextElementSibling.innerText, ul);
    });

    // insertion re-factors HTMl to ensure the layout (markup and CSS) when displaed
    headlines.parentNode.insertBefore(ul, headlines.nextSibling)
}

// once prepared, we can display the loaded content as snippet/collection 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createsnippets);
```

Comment: `I tried to change using destructuring but didn't work` - where did you do this? no evidence of destructuring in the code you posted

Comment: here, you can see in this link  - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/yqoxcLfb/42/

Comment: naming variables `t` `v` or `p` also not professionally looking

Comment: With deconstructing, the browser keeps giving me an error message that can't find the h4 variable.

Comment: how about putting the jsfiddle code in the question ... seems easy enough

Comment: see the code that is commented `// create the list for reference` ... where's h4 declared there? hint: it isn't - there's also a reference to a `ul` variable also undeclared - the line from this code `let ul = create('ul', null, document.body);` seems to not be in the jsfiddle code ... it's like it's two different pieces of code